# From MongoDB to a Pandas data frame

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pandas, dataframe

I have a collection in my MongoDB database, where each record represents an edge(a road in the application I am building). Each record has the following form where the first `id` is the `id` of the edge:

```js
{  
   "_id":{  
      "$oid":"5d0e7acc9c0bd9917006dd56"
   },
   "edge":{  
      "@id":":3659704519_0",
      "@traveltime":"2.37",
      "@timestep":"3",
      "lane":[  
         {  
            "@id":":3330548807_1_0",
            "@maxspeed":"1",
            "@meanspeed":"79.99",
            "@occupancy":"0.00",
            "@shape":"11.735290362905872,48.16774527062213,11.735369706697464,48.16778792148228"
         },
         {  
            "@id":":3330548807_1_1",
            "@maxspeed":"1",
            "@meanspeed":"79.99",
            "@occupancy":"0.00",
            "@shape":"11.73526233983474,48.16776717333565,11.735343756121146,48.16781085462666"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I want to do some analysis with those data and I want to convert the records to a data frame in pandas.
The desired data frame skeleton would be like this:

[the desirable skeleton for the data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFOUu.png)

I have tried normalizing with `pandas.io.json.json_normalize(d)` but I cannot get the output I want.

As we can see I have an array of lanes that can have a maximum of two lanes. It can also contain only one lane. So, I want to separate the lanes into two rows of the data frame.

Could someone please suggest a solution to me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your data is nested like yours you have to transform it to a flat shape before you can create a data frame.

```
import pandas

json = [
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5d0e7acc9c0bd9917006dd56"
   },
   "edge":{
      "@id":":3659704519_0",
      "@traveltime":"2.37",
      "@timestep":"3",
      "lane": [
         {
            "@id":":3330548807_1_0",
            "@maxspeed":"1",
            "@meanspeed":"79.99",
            "@occupancy":"0.00",
            "@shape":"11.735290362905872,48.16774527062213,11.735369706697464,48.16778792148228"
         },
         {
            "@id":":3330548807_1_1",
            "@maxspeed":"1",
            "@meanspeed":"79.99",
            "@occupancy":"0.00",
            "@shape":"11.73526233983474,48.16776717333565,11.735343756121146,48.16781085462666"
         }
      ]
   }
},
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"5d0e7acc9c0bd9917006dd56"
   },
   "edge":{
      "@id":":3659704519_0",
      "@traveltime":"2.37",
      "@timestep":"3",
      "lane":{
            "@id":":3330548807_1_0",
            "@maxspeed":"1",
            "@meanspeed":"79.99",
            "@occupancy":"0.00",
            "@shape":"11.735290362905872,48.16774527062213,11.735369706697464,48.16778792148228"
      }
   }
},
]

def ensure_list(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return obj
    else:
        return [obj]

json_transformed = [
    {
        # edge attributes
        'edge_id': record['edge']['@id'],
        # lane attributes
        'lane_id': lane['@id'],
        # ...
    }
    for record in json
    for lane in ensure_list(record['edge']['lane'])
]

df = pandas.DataFrame(json_transformed)
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not work in the cases when there is only one lane. And also, the data that I get comes from MongoDB. Please check my question again because I made a mistake about the format of the records.

Comment: You did not share how the record look if only one lane is present. As the previous version did not work for you i guess it is an object.  I made an update to work independently of if lane is a list or an object.

Comment: Your solution works very well when the data is given like you have declared it. However, because I need to get my data from my MongoDB database, I am storing the data in a variable like this json_data = db.json_data
json = list(json_data.find({})).    However, I am getting an error like this: KeyError: 'lane'. I do not know what is the problem .Everything should work just fine.

Comment: is it possible that 1. `lane` is actually `@lane` if there is only one lane or 2. that there are objects without lanes at all? KeyError means that there is no attribute lane in the object.